# Calculate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^{\sin(x)}}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, indeterminate-forms

Calculate $$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1}{x^{\sin(x)}}$$

I'm pretty much clueless here, only that there is L'hospital obviously here.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hint: Find the limit of the $\log$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It usually helps to consider the log of the expression in such limits:

$$\log{\left [ x^{-\sin{x}} \right ]} = -\sin{x} \log{x} $$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sin{x} \log{x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x \log{x} = 0 $$

The limit in question, therefore, is 1.

**EDIT**

I can be a little more clear on using L'Hopital on the above limit:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x \log{x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\log{x}}{1/x} $$

Now use L'Hopital:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\log{x}}{1/x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1/x}{-1/x^2} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (-x) $$

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really understand why it means the limit is 1... I'll be happy to get a clarification. Thanks!

Comment: If $\log{a} = 0$, then $a=1$.  This follows from $e^0 = 1$.  Recall that we took the log of the expression in the 1st step.

Comment: @Harold: see the other answer - which showed the process of setting up the problem a bit more clearly

Comment: I guess this is more clearer $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \sin (x) \log (x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin (x)}{x} x \log (x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} \;  \lim_{x \to 0} x \log x = 1 \cdot 0  = 0$$

Comment: No, I'd say it is about as clear, as it relies on the same point: that $\sin{x} \sim x$ as $x \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$ x^{-\sin x} = \left( e^{\ln(x) } \right) ^{-\sin x} = e^{-\sin x \ln (x)}$$

Since this is of indeterminate from, we can apply L'hopital rule here.
$$ \large \lim_{x \to 0} x^{-\sin x} =  e^{\lim_{x \to 0}  \left( \frac{-\sin x}{\frac{1}{\ln x}} \right)}$$

Comment: Why isn't it then $$ \large \lim_{x \to 0} x^{-\sin x} =  {\lim_{x \to 0}  e^\left( \frac{-\sin x}{\frac{1}{\ln x}} \right)}$$

Comment: @Harold due to this property of limit $\lim_{x\to 0} g(f(x)) = g( \lim_{x\to 0} f(x))$

Comment: Harold: this set up allows you to use L'hospital. You can evaluate the $$\large \lim_{x \to 0} x^{-\sin x} =  {\lim_{x \to 0}  e^\left( \frac{-\sin x}{\frac{1}{\ln x}} \right)} =  e^{\lim_{x \to 0}  \left( \frac{-\sin x}{\frac{1}{\ln x}} \right)}$$

Comment: @Harold also note that $ \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) g(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}f(x) \lim_{x \to 0}g(x)$ which allows you the other answer without using L'hopital rule

Comment: @experimentX elegant answer.

Answer (score 2):

Things are simple if we use the elementary limits $\lim_{x\to 0}x^x=1$ and$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1}{x^{\sin(x)}}=\lim_{x\to 0} x^{\displaystyle x\frac{\sin(x)}{x} (-1)}=1$$

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that uses neither L'Hospital's Rule nor logarithms.  Rather, it relies only on standard inequalities from geometry along with the Squeze Theorem.

To that end, we proceed by recalling that for $x\ge 0$ the sine function satisfies the inequalities

$$x\cos x\le \sin x\le x \tag 1$$

From $(1)$ it is easy to show that for $0\le x\le 1$ we have

$$x\sqrt{1-x^2} \le \sin x\le x \tag 2$$

Then, using $(2)$, we have for $0\le x\le 1$

$$\left(\frac1x\right)^{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\le \left(\frac1x\right)^{\sin x}\le \left(\frac1x\right)^{x} \tag 3$$

Using $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^x=1$ in $(3)$ along with the Squeeze Theorem reveals

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac1x\right)^{\sin x}=1$$

Comment: Was there a vote change?